# How to add padding to HTML text elements like <code> without getting gaps in text selection background color

Tags: html, css

I want some padding on `code` elements but when I apply padding it causes gaps in the selection background color when the text is highlighted. How can I prevent these gaps?

https://codepen.io/pen/MWrpbWj

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure you can without some messy JS because the styling possibilities of a selection are so limited. BTW it happens e.g. with span - it's not because they are code elements particularly - and I suppose in a way it's giving an indication of what is actually selected e.g. if it's then copied it's the text, not the blank areas which are not space characters.